# cfquery oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, cfquery

I had to change the SQL stored procedure to ORacle stored procddure.I am able to successfully execute my modified stored procedure in oracle.

But unable to obtain the query result in CF for  the Oracle stored-Procedure.I have used `<cfquery>`.

```
Any suggestions or tips to for using an Oracle stored proc/CF-8?
```

Comment: Could you post your <cfquery>? It's hard to determine the issue without the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think you need *cfstoredproc*, not *cfquery*.

See [manual page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_r-s_22.html#2916700) for more details.

Comment: Agreed. I don't know how well Oracle reacts to procedure calls in CFQUERY, especially if you want results back. I know for sure that CFSTOREDPROC works as I use it frequently.

Answer (score 0):

It does really depend on how it reacts, i'd test your stored proc in oracle sql+plus first, to make sure it returns data, then try it via cfquery or stored procedure...